# Как из потока WinAPI получить HANDLE этого потока, который был возвращён при его создании?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi

Создаю поток функцией `CreateThread`, которая возвращает `HANDLE` на созданный поток. Есть задача: получить **именно этот** `HANDLE`, только уже изнутри потока. Гугл посоветовал `OpenThread(..., ..., GetCurrentThreadId())`, однако эта функция возвращает **новый** `HANDLE` на этот поток, а мне, повторюсь, нужен тот самый, который был возвращён при создании.

Comment: Это случаем не задача XY? Зачем получать именно тот дескриптор? Ну а если и получать, то что мешает передать его обычным способом?

Comment: @user7860670, нет, это не та задача. Передать обычным способом мешает то, что программа многопоточная и имеет достаточно сложную структуру.

Answer (score 2):

Во первых, хандл действует только в рамках одного процесса. Для каждого отдельного процесса таблица хандлов своя. Во вторых, у одного thread впринципе может быть несколько хандлов. Но если хандл один - то можно его получить лишь сканированием всех хандлов процесса.

Можно например с помощью GetThreadId http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreadid

Я приведу упрощенный пример

```
 HANDLE getThreadHandleById(DWORD id) {
    for (i=4;i<1000;i+=4)
      if (GetThreadId((HANDLE)i) == id) return (HANDLE)i;
    return (HANDLE)NULL; // А может уже thread не живой или плохо просканировали таблицу
    );

HANDLE myId = getThreadHandleById(GetCurrentThreadId());
```

Вместо 1000 должен быть максимальный номер хандла, только узнать его не так просто. Есть общее к-во хандлов, я беру общее к-во и умножаю на 1,5*4 = 6. (Хандлы по-моему опыту идут каждые 4). Возможно в даном конкретном случае лучше бесконечный цикл.

Можно улучшить программу используя ф-ции NtQueryObject, NtQueryInformationThread.

P.S. GetCurrentThread - возвращает константное значение - псевдохэндл, которое будет всегда означать текущий поток, даже если он уже сменился. Поэтому его нельзя передавать в другие потоки. В большинстве случаев GetCurrentThread вполне достаточно. Но если у вас многозадачность и попался случай что GetCurrentThread не подходит - то чаще всего Handle задачи передают процедуре, которая обрабатывает задачу, и "вычисление" хандла не делается. Если вам приходится использовать данный код - то... или вы внедряетесь в чужой код (или боритесь с чужими криво-написаными библиотеками), или вы неправильно написали код и я советую пробросить хандл задачи и не терять его. Хотя... "стартовый" хандл-thread пожалуй обычным способом нельзя достать, но я не могу придумать задачу где это нужно. Если у вас один поток - используйте просто `GetCurrentThread()`.

UDP Ещё вариант, если вам просто нужно проверить "свой" "чужой", и не нужно передавать хандл в функции которые принимают хандл (SuspendThread ResumeThread TerminateThread Set/GetThreadContext и подобные которые управляют thread-ами) - то вы можете использовать Thread-Id вместо Thread-Handle. Тогда вам нужно `GetCurrentThreadId()` и всё. Одну вы получите при входе, а вторую можно получить либо повторным вызовом `GetCurrentThreadId()` либо через `CreateThread`.

Comment: `GetCurrentThread` возвращает псевдохэндл, который может быть использован только внутри вызывающего потока, но его нельзя передавать в другие потоки и т.п. Если хэндл необходимо использовать где-то извне, то надо задублировать хэндл с помощью `DuplicateHandle`.